# Get all latest() from model

Tags: django, postgresql, optimization

This is a pseudoview of my structure:

```
Offer [id, match]
    - Odds [id, offer_id, time)
    - Odds [id, offer_id, time)
    - .....
```

To get the latest object based on the `time` attribute, I would simply do `someOffer.latest()`. My problem is querying for `latest()` on multiple offers. I started going `[offer.odds.latest() for o in Offer.objects.filter....]` - which is obviously too many queries, thus really slow. Then I structured this query

```
Odds.objects.annotate(max_time=Max('offer__odds__time')).filter(time=F('max_time'))
```

which is a lot faster. However, this is very, very slow on a large set of Odds ( > 100,000 ). Does anyone have a good way of fetching all the "latest" of multiple objects?

Thanks alot,

Comment: In raw SQL you'd join on a subquery in the FROM clause that found the max(...) for each object in question. Not sure how to express that in Django-ORM-ish though.

Comment: I think using this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods might help here.